# How do i combine a variable that returns three distinct array into one array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a variable say `$a` that returns the following arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 759
            [1] => 757
            [2] => 467
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 759
            [1] => 757
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 759
            [1] => 467
        )

)
```

How do i make combine them into a single array using PHP?

Comment: you can use the array_merge function

Comment: As said by the above commentary, you may use array_merge but it depends of the output array's format you want

Comment: 1. What would be the expected output? 2. What have you tried?

Comment: For those of us suggesting `array_merge`, i don't think it will work.

Show me a code example let me see.

Comment: With regret I have downvoted this question, as I think questions should be accompanied with more prior effort, and some of the responses are rather inviting others to do all the work ("Show me a code example let me see" and "[I've] updated the question code. [Please] update your code"). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `array_walk_recursive` with `in_array` check:

```
$final = array();

array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) use (&$final){
    if(!in_array($item, $final)) $final[] = $item;
});
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/323932)

Comment: i've updated the question code. please update your code. thanks.

Comment: @Collizo4sky: My answer was already based on the updated structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge();](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php) ; and a little foreach since you don't know the number of subarrays you're going to have :

```
  foreach ($array as $listOfArrays) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $array);
}
```

Since you've got an array of arrays, just send array_merge your sub-arrays.

Comment: Array_merge won't work unless am missing something.

Note, the arrays are encapsulated in a parent array. see the updated code.

Comment: @Collizo4sky   Merge should work, i uploaded my answer to suits your need.

Comment: The problem is, i don't know how many array the variable will contain.

can you rewrite the code into a function that accept a multi-dimensional of different number of child-arrays like the one in my question and merge them?

Comment: what is the value of $result?

Since $result in array_merge isn't an array, it will result to an error.

Could you please use the sample array in my question to show me how it will work?

Comment: @Collizo4sky try this code, it works. $result will be at the first iteration an array, then an array, then an array ... It's basic PHP stuff there.